# If $a+b+c$ divides the product $abc$, then is $(a,b,c)$ a Pythagorean Triple?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles, conjectures, pythagorean-triples

Firstly, I will define what *Pythagorean Triples* are for those who do not know.

> > **Definition:**
>
> A Pythagorean Triple is a group of three integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, since the *Pythagorean Theorem* asserts that for any $90^\circ$ (right-angle) triangle $ABC$ with sides $a$, $b$ and $c$, one will always have the equation, $a^2+b^2=c^2$.
>
> [image: Right-Angle Triangle ABC]

---

I was looking at Pythagorean Triples and noticed another property apart from how $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Here are the first $30$ Pythagorean Triples $(a,b,c)$ ordered from smallest to greatest value, i.e. $$(a,b,c)\qquad\text{ s.t. }\qquad a<b<c.\tag*{$\big(\text{s.t. = such that}\big)$}$$

[image: First 30 Pythagorean Triples]

---

I noticed that $a^2=(c+b)(c-b)$, but that is trivial since $$\begin{align}a^2&=(c+b)(c-b)\tag{given} \\ &=c^2-b^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow\,\,\,\, a^2+b^2&=c^2.\end{align}$$

---

However, I also noticed that by having "$u\mid v$" be read as *"$u$ divides $v$",* it appears that $$a+b+c\mid abc.$$ For example, $(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$ is a classic Pythagorean Triple; $3^2+4^2=5^2$.

Also, $$\begin{align}3+4+5&=12 \\ \& \quad3\times 4\times 5 &= 60. \\ \\ 12 &\,\mid 60 \\ \Leftrightarrow \,\,\,\,3+4+5&\,\mid 3\times 4\times 5.\end{align}$$ This, I cannot prove to be true $-$ but I tested with all the $30$ Pythagorean Triples above, and I have come across no counter-example. Is there a proof? I do not know where to begin myself.

---

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> Given three positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a < b<c$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $$a+b+c\mid abc.$$

---

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

My conjecture was originally the other way round; i.e. if $a+b+c\mid abc$ then $a^2+b^2=c^2$. But $6$ is a counter-example, namely because it is a  [*Perfect Number*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectNumber.html).

Comment: Take $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$ in the conjecture. Then $a+b+c=6$ divides $abc=6$, but $1^2+2^2\neq 3^2$.

Comment: Wow that is a counter-example! Looks like I have to restate my conjecture :)

Comment: @user477343 perhaps you want the converse; in your example you've taken a Pythagorean triple and verified that the desired property holds.

Comment: If you had hypothesis and think that you found a new similar conjecture, you should work with Newton's polynom associated to $(a,b, c)$

Comment: The converse is certainly true. Pythagorean triples can be expressed as $$a=k (m^2-n^2) \qquad b = 2 m n k \qquad c = k ( m^2 + n^2 )$$ for some integers $m$, $n$, $k$. (See Wikipedia's ["Pythagorean triple"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) entry.)

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg yes you are most likely correct :)

Comment: The converse is an easy consequence of the characterization of Pythagorean triplets. Put $a=x^2-y^2$,  $b=2xy$ and $c=x^2+y^2$, and the result will be straightforward.

Comment: @user477343 may be the conjecture should be 
` If $a<b<c$ and $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ then $a+b+c |abc$.`

Comment: @Pagode I am unaware of that polynomial. Please explain :)

Comment: @David ok :) ${}$

Comment: Newton's polynoms could design different things :

Comment: Here I mean : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: @Pagode thank you very much. I will look into it :) ...... I see what you mean. So I just have a case where $$e_1(a^2,b^2,c^2)\mid e_3(a^2,b^2,c^2)\;?$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually want it the other way around: if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then $a+b+c|abc$. That you can prove very quickly from the general form of primitive Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)=(m^2-n^2,2mn,m^2+n^2)$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}a+b+c&=(m^2-n^2)+(2mn)+(m^2+n^2)\\ &=(m^2+m^2)+2mn+(n^2-n^2) \\ &=2m^2+2mn \\ &=2m(m+n).\end{align}$$ And now $abc=2mn(m^4-n^4)$ so I must show that $m+n\mid n(m^4-n^4)$ which means $n\mid m$. But $m$ and $n$ are arbitrary. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $x^4-y^4 = (x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2) = (x-y)(x+y)(x
^2+y^2)$

Comment: $a+b+c=2m^2+2mn=2m(m+n) $, while $abc={\bf 2m}n(m^2+n^2)(m-n){\bf (m+n)} $.

Comment: @Stefan thank you very much. I was able to put to-and-to together :)

Comment: @Berci thank you also very much. I forgot I could also factorise $m^2-n^2$ and cancel out the like expression, namely $(m+n)$ :)

Comment: Congratulations, Michael! You have a tick! $$\color{green}{\checkmark} \ \ (+1)$$

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively:
$$\frac{abc}{a+b+c}=\frac{abc(a+b-c)}{(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}=\frac{abc(a+b-c)}{2ab}=\frac{c(a+b-c)}{2},$$
which is a positive integer for both cases: $a,b,c$ are all even; $a,c$ are odd and $b$ is even.

Comment: I am glad you used a conjugate method. I only use those to rationalise denominators. I did not know you could use that technique in this case. $(+1)$. There is, however, also another case, where $c$ is even and $a+b>c$, such that $a$ and $b$ are both odd or even.

Comment: It follows that $a+b+c\mid ab$.

Comment: Also, the integer factor $\tfrac12(a+b-c)=r$
is the radius of inscribed circle.

Comment: @g.kov I knew the first part... but not the second. Is the inscribed circle the circle drawn inside the triangle such that the circumference is just touching the legs and hypotenuse? I assume I understand what "inscribed" means, hahah :)